# Pandas group the rows in a dataframe based on specific column value

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have the data frame as like below one,

```
Input DataFrame
     gw_mac                 mac
 0   ac233fc015f6           dce83f3bc820
 1   ac233fc015f6           ac233f264a4c
 2   ac233fc015f6           ac233f264a4c
 3   ac233fc015f6           dce83f3bc820
 4   ac233fc015f6           ac233f264a4c
 5   ac233fc015f6           ac233f264a4c
 6   ac233fc015f6           dce83f3bc820
 7   ac233fc015f6           e464eecba5eb
```

Now I need to group the dataframe based on the column values "gw_mac" and "mac" and I should get the following three different groups

```
Expected Output
Group1

     gw_mac                 mac
 0   ac233fc015f6           dce83f3bc820
 3   ac233fc015f6           dce83f3bc820
 6   ac233fc015f6           dce83f3bc820

Group2
      gw_mac                 mac
  1   ac233fc015f6           ac233f264a4c
  2   ac233fc015f6           ac233f264a4c
  4   ac233fc015f6           ac233f264a4c
  5   ac233fc015f6           ac233f264a4c

Group3
      gw_mac                 mac
  7   ac233fc015f6           e464eecba5eb
```

Comment: Grouping the dataframe by both the columns will return the required groups. How do you want to aggregate them? list(df.groupby(['gw_mac', 'mac']))

Comment: @Vaishali, Grouping should return as dataframe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If need different groups by columns loop by `groupby` object:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(['gw_mac','mac']):
    print (g)
         gw_mac           mac
1  ac233fc015f6  ac233f264a4c
2  ac233fc015f6  ac233f264a4c
4  ac233fc015f6  ac233f264a4c
5  ac233fc015f6  ac233f264a4c
         gw_mac           mac
0  ac233fc015f6  dce83f3bc820
3  ac233fc015f6  dce83f3bc820
6  ac233fc015f6  dce83f3bc820
         gw_mac           mac
7  ac233fc015f6  e464eecba5eb
```

Comment: Will this be a time consuming one?

Comment: @MahamuthaM - It is only looping, it depends what need next do.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this to create a dictionary of data frames with unique groups,

```
df['Group'] = df.groupby(['gw_mac', 'mac']).cumcount()

dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Group')))
```

You can access a group using,

```
dfs[0]

    gw_mac          mac             Group
0   ac233fc015f6    dce83f3bc820    0
1   ac233fc015f6    ac233f264a4c    0
7   ac233fc015f6    e464eecba5eb    0
```